# In-App Purchase Crashes Occasionally

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have an app that is released and the in-app purchase seems to work on occasions as users have purchased, but i am noticing on Crashlytics(fabric) that the app keeps crashing and i cant figure out why since i cannot replicate the crash on any device. This is my first integration of in-app purchases so bear with me.

I cant figure out whats wrong, especially since there is no pattern to a specific device, and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't (apparently). I get that this can have multiple causes but a nudge in the right direction would be great.
Here's the crash log

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  app                            0xc2658 WelcomeViewController.purchaseAlert() -> () (WelcomeViewController.swift)
1  app                            0xc2658 WelcomeViewController.purchaseAlert() -> () (WelcomeViewController.swift)
2  app                            0xc1148 @objc WelcomeViewController.removeAdsTapped(UIButton) -> () (WelcomeViewController.swift:164)
3  UIKit                          0x29691771 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
4  UIKit                          0x29691701 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 64
5  UIKit                          0x2967961f -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 446
6  UIKit                          0x29691051 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 616
7  UIKit                          0x29690cbf -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 646
8  UIKit                          0x296895d7 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 642
9  UIKit                          0x2965a119 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 204
10 UIKit                          0x29658757 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 5134
11 CoreFoundation                 0x25485257 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
12 CoreFoundation                 0x25484e47 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 454
13 CoreFoundation                 0x254831af __CFRunLoopRun + 806
14 CoreFoundation                 0x253d5bb9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
15 CoreFoundation                 0x253d59ad CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
16 GraphicsServices               0x2664faf9 GSEventRunModal + 160
17 UIKit                          0x296c1fb5 UIApplicationMain + 144
18 app                            0xbaba4 main (AppDelegate.swift:15)
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x25088873 (Missing)
```

Anything that i'm missing?

**Edit:**

This is what gets called when the user taps the remove ads button

```
 func purchaseAlert() {


        let priceFormatter: NSNumberFormatter = {

            let pf = NSNumberFormatter()
            pf.formatterBehavior = .Behavior10_4
            pf.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
            return pf


        }()

        priceFormatter.locale = storeProducts.first!.priceLocale

        let productPrice = storeProducts.first!.price

      let price = priceFormatter.stringFromNumber(productPrice)!

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Remove Ads for \(price)", message: "This purchase will remove all ad's that show through out the app", preferredStyle: .Alert)

         alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go Back", style: .Default, handler: nil))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Remove Ad's", style: .Default, handler: { (_) -> Void in


            self.removeADs()

        }))




        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

The purchase product

```
 func removeADs() {

        let product = storeProducts.first

        Purchasables.store.purchaseProduct(product!)


    }
```

This assumes that there will always be a product, and there should be.

**Update:**
I've updated the app and waited more than a week to get some data and turns out that users still aren't able to purchase. I now safely unwrap all optionals so there is no nil values so that leads to no crashes, but i've been tracking taps on the *remove ads button* and i notice that i get something like this (20taps,10 users) indicating that users keep tapping again and again and results in no purchases. I've also tracked to see if there is a product returned from the store, and 97% of the time there is. I still can't pin point the issue, and the taps on the button definitely are not accidental since the remove ads button is pretty much out of the way. I still get some purchases going through, but most fail.

Comment: Can you post some of the relevant bits of your  in app purchases code. Hard to tell you from just looking at this error

Comment: Sure, i've added more code. What confuses me is that some users are able to make purchases and most are not. I've tried different stores different devices and still couldn't replicate the issue.

Comment: argh its hard for me to help because you can't replicate the issue thus you get no error messages to see whats happening. Its frustrating I know, I am having a problem with my game too where I am having a bug that apples review team tells me about that I cannot for the life of me replicate.

Comment: What you can try to just make your code a bit more robust is safely unwrapping your optionals, like storeProducts.first!.price. Maybe for some users its nil causing a crash.

Comment: I will post an answer to show what I mean, not sure this will help but it might at least makes your code a bit safer.

Comment: I just posted the answer, not sure it will help. If you could replicate maybe it would be easier

Comment: Thanks, definitely the bewildering part is that some users experience the crash some aren't. Though i am suspecting it might have to do something with the pricing format will have to check. Hope you solve the issue with your game.

Answer (score 1):

Still hard to help you without any crashes or xCode errors that you can replicate. However like I said you can at least improve your code to make sure there can be no crashes where values are nil.

So you should change your purchase alert func to this

```
 func purchaseAlert() {


    let priceFormatter: NSNumberFormatter = {

        let pf = NSNumberFormatter()
        pf.formatterBehavior = .Behavior10_4
        pf.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
        return pf


    }()

    /// safely unwrap storeProducts.first! to ensure its not nil
    /// if its nil than exit the method 
    guard let firstStoreProduct = storeProducts.first! else { return }

    // no more ! needed at the end which might caused a crash before
    priceFormatter.locale = firstStoreProduct.priceLocale

    // safely create the product price, if you can't exit the method
    guard let productPrice = firstStoreProduct.price else { return }

    // no more ! needed at the end which might also caused a crash before because product price cannot be nil anymore when getting to this line
    let price = priceFormatter.stringFromNumber(productPrice)


    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Remove Ads for \(price)", message: "This purchase will remove all ad's that show through out the app", preferredStyle: .Alert)

     alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go Back", style: .Default, handler: nil))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Remove Ad's", style: .Default, handler: { (_) -> Void in


        self.removeADs()

    }))




    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

As you can see I use 2 guard statements (same as if let) to safely unwrap stuff. I prefer it this way than using "if let" pyramids. You can change it to "if let" if you dont like it this way or for some reason dont want to return from the method early if there was an error.

Your remove ads method should look like this

```
 func removeADs() {

    if let product = storeProducts.first! {

         Purchasables.store.purchaseProduct(product)
     }
}
```

This way you are getting rid of some of the ! where you are unwrapping values without ensuring they are not nil.
I would need to see your array or dictionaries and related code to maybe further identify what could be nil.

Comment: Need to do this, tough i did follow a guide to set up the iap so i'm going to blame it on the guide, hah. But in this case this helped since a value seems to be nil and if i would've safely unwrapped the optionals i would have had no idea that users aren't able to purchase. So that's why i need to track the taps on the remove ad's button. Thanks i'll do this and after the update goes live i'll update.

Comment: No problem, keep us posted if it fixe the crashed

Comment: The crash is fixed but the problem remains. I've updated my post if you want to be bewildered a bit.

Comment: I dont know man I would need to see your whole code that relates to in app purchases

Comment: No worries, i'll re-implement the code, just thought i'd give a quick update on the issue.

Comment: Cool, keep us posted. I more than willing to help but like I said I would need to see more code

Comment: Sure, thanks. I'll let you know if the update code still wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem 1 month ago, no crash always only in 90% of cases. This is a Apple´s Bug, the thread doesn´t stop I don´t know why... But to solve this I cancel the request (SKProductsRequest) and it works fine:

```
var request: SKProductsRequest! //global to cancel when disappear
//request products when you want (viewDidLoad for example)
request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
```

And when disappear viewcontroller:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        request.delegate = nil;
        request.cancel()
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(self)
    }
```